# Upgrading to SSD in an old laptop with SATA controller Intel 82801IBM/IEM

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I have an old Sony laptop with Intel's 82801IBM/IEM SATA controller. Now, I am planning to buy a Samsung EVO 250GB SSD. Will this SSD be compatible with my laptop.

I am not that good in hardware jargon. So which factors should I consider before buying this SSD regarding compatibility. Will I be able to reap all the SSD's benefits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSD will work fine - You will notice a considerable speed difference, the laptop will be quieter and the battery will last a bit longer.

It's easily the most significant upgrade you can perform on an old laptop with SATA.

The SSD you are buying is capable of faster speeds than your laptop can reach, but this won't make a difference due to backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I have here a notebook using a 82801IBM/IEM controller. I have tried to replace the hard disk by a more modern one (WD10JPLX) having a SATA-3 interface. I was not successful. The BIOS was not able to perform the boot time self test. I was forced to return to the old disk.